# Adding html data attributes from asp.net with a datasource

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I am working on a asp.net program and i ran into a problem where i need to add data attributes to a html combobox. The combobox is being created from code behind using a data source.

the code for it is as followed.

```
cboInventoryCategory.DataSource = assetInfo.categories;
cboInventoryCategory.DataValueField = "id";
cboInventoryCategory.DataTextField = "text";    
cboInventoryCategory.DataBind();
```

Now would it be possible to add a additional attribute that i can later retrieve in javascript from here? These values will be different for every item. Or will i have to pass the data to javascript and add it in from there?

Here is something i tried but it was not working.

```
cboInventoryCategory.DataSource = assetInfo.categories;
cboInventoryCategory.DataValueField = "id";
cboInventoryCategory.DataTextField = "text";
cboInventoryCategory.Attributes["data-depreciationPercentage"] = "DepreciationPercentage";
cboInventoryCategory.DataBind();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I resolved it at the end by just passing data to javascript and rebuilding my combobox there. But if there is a way to do it from code behind i would like to know so please comment.